# Can I send math subject GRE scores to programs that do not require them?

Tags: graduate-admissions, gre

I'm applying math graduate program and know that some program reads "gre math subject is not required". Does that mean I can't send gre subject score to them?

And if I also want to apply cs program, can I send gre math sub score to them to exhibit my mathematical ability?

Answer (score 6):

You can still send it in. You can always add more information to your application, but there is no guarantee that they will consider it. I know a few schools have stopped asking for GRE subject scores because they don't feel that it's a good way to predict performance, and if that is the case they will not look at it. Assuming you have a good score, it will not count against you.

Answer (score 2):

You can and should send them. Not required means it is not essential; they don't want someone who has not taken that exam to worry. But grad schools would typically want to know about a candidate from as many sources as possible and getting your subject GRE scores is really a good plus point for your candidature. Of course , additional fee for each report has to be borne