# Should I submit my math subject GRE score?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, mathematics, gre

I'm a US student applying to PhD programs in pure mathematics this semester. Most of the programs I am applying to are highly ranked schools which are making the subject GRE optional this semester. That being said, I scored an 810 (76th percentile) on the exam in September. I believe an 810 would usually correspond to a higher percentile (maybe 80th) regularly, but I assume that since the test is optional this round, the pool of people taking the exam is better than usual. I was wondering if, assuming the rest of my application is quite strong, I should submit this score. I'm not sure if this makes a difference but I also happen to be an ethnic minority (latino). Thanks.

Comment: There's a section in this question about GRE scores. https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-ph-d-programs-in-the-us-particularly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I send math subject GRE scores to programs that do not require them?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/36558/can-i-send-math-subject-gre-scores-to-programs-that-do-not-require-them)

Comment: @GoodDeeds Not really since the user in that post didn't post what their score was. I'm not sure if my score is high enough to warrant sending in. Obviously it wouldn't be a good idea to send in a score <50th percentile assuming the rest of your application is strong for instance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in the US, particularly for weak or borderline students?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-ph-d-programs-in-the-us-particularly)

Answer (score 4):

Probably you should just go ahead and do it.  In particular, I think reading an application with no GRE score, I generally would guess the score is lower than the one you listed (though, this year, who knows).  It's impossible to fully predict the effect it has (most notably, you don't mention how strong the rest of your application is), but I think at most programs the GRE score is used try to sort out which students have reasonable preparation vs. those who don't, and your score is good enough to indicate reasonable preparation.  I don't think many people count on it to sort out who the very best applicants are.

Answer (score 4):

When I review grad school applications, the math subject GRE scores are usually a binary pre-filter. If someone scores below our cutoff (which is usually a 600 for MS, 650 for PhD), they are pretty much automatically removed. We need students who can assist in teaching undergrad math and they need to at least have some base competency.

That is the extent of our use of the subject GRE.

I would report your scores if you have them. Your scores are high enough that I'm guessing most programs will not even think twice about them.