Will subject GRE scores in the 75th percentile be helpful for phd applications at top schools? Or is it better not to send scores?
I am an international (Asian) applying this December applying for grad school.
My pGRE score is 870 (75%).
I am applying to some ivy league schools and top tier schools. Should I report the scores?

Related question about math GRE with similar score: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/176596/17254
